# Excel WORKDAY.INTL Formula - Need Help Finding my Mistake - Formula Appears to be Miscalculating Date

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image: Excel Workbook Screenshot]

**Purpose of Post**

Trying to determine why the `WORKDAY.INTL` formula in cell "F2" of the attached workbook picture seems to be calculating the incorrect date. I expected the date be 8/16/21. It is showing as 8/12/21.

The attached picture is a screenshot of my workbook that contains a table of tasks. The columns to the right of the tasks column are explained below.

- Start Date: the date that the task will be started.
- Due Date: the date that the task is due/will be finished.
- Hours of Work: the estimated amount of hours that it will take to complete the task.
- Percent Dedication: The percentage of my time in a workday that I will dedicate to that task.
- Start Date Check: Calculates the latests day you can start the task to finish on the specified due date given the hours of work required and the percent dedication.
- Due Date Check: Calculates when the work will be finished if started on the specified start date given the hours of work required and the percent dedication.
- Working Hours: Number of hours in each working day.

**Formulas in Cells**

Cell "E2": `=([@[Hours of Work]]/(NETWORKDAYS.INTL([@[Start Date]],[@[Due Date]],"0000111")*J1))`

Cell "F2": `=WORKDAY.INTL([@[Due Date]],(-1)*([@[Hours of Work]]/([@[Percent Dedication]]*J1))+1,"0000111")`

Cell "G2": `=WORKDAY.INTL([@[Start Date]],[@[Hours of Work]]/([@[Percent Dedication]]*J1)-1,"0000111")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your problem in it's simplest form:

[image: Original problem, but simpler]

Column `C` shows the formulas that are being used in Column `B`.

The formula in `B3` is displaying the correct answer.

However, the formula in `B4` treats `B3` as though it is `-11`. This is almost certainly due to floating-point arithmetic, especially considering that the `10/11` part of the formula is a non-terminating number. This is much too complicated of a subject to get into, but essentially it means that the result is not `-10` and is something like `-10.0000000...00000004815162342` because of the slight imprecision.

The solution is to round the result to an integer, so that we ignore the tiny amount of imprecision. For our test case, we would do this:

[image: Revised problem]

By rounding the answer, we have obtained the correct result.

For your workbook we can do the same thing. The formula in `E2` would become:

`=WORKDAY.INTL([@[Due Date]],ROUND(-([@[Hours of Work]]/([@[Percent Dedication]]*J1))+1,0),"0000111")`

Which gives the correct answer:

[image]

I would suggest doing the same for the formula in `G2` as well, which would be:

`=WORKDAY.INTL([@[Start Date]],ROUND([@[Hours of Work]]/([@[Percent Dedication]]*J1)-1,0),"0000111")`